# Best way to select parts certain parts of data in a string that changes in size

Tags: java, string, xml-parsing, substring, string-parsing

I'm looking for a good method of parsing certain parts of information in a string that changes in size.

For example, the string might be

> "id:1234 alert:a-b up:12.3 down:12.3"

and I need to pick out the value for `id`, `alert`, `up` and `down` so my initial thought was substring but then I thought that length of the string can change in size for example

> "id:123456 alert:a-b-c-d up:12.345 down:12.345"

So using substring each time to look at say characters 3 to 7 may not work each time because it would not capture all of the data needed.

What would be a smart way of selecting each value that is needed? Hopefully I've explained this well as I normally tend to confuse people with my bad explanations. I am programming in Java.

Comment: You need to better describe what you are searching for in your strings. Are you always looking for `<word>: <value>`? Where `<word>` and `<value>` contain no spaces? As a side note, you don't need to pepper your question with `<br>`s. That's what the ENTER key is for.

Comment: @brookman If the `<word>:<value>` pair doesn't contain any spaces, you can first split using space and later by colon(:) for each `<word>:<value>` pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), first to tokenize the whitespace and then to tokenize on your key/value separator (colon in this case):

```
String line = "id:1234   alert:a-b   up:12.3 down:12.3";
// first split the line by whitespace
String[] keyValues = line.split("\\s+");

for (String keyValueString : keyValues) {
    String[] keyValue = keyValueString.split(":");
    // TODO might want to check for bad data, that we have 2 values
    System.out.println(String.format("Key: %-10s Value: %-10s", keyValue[0], keyValue[1]));
}
```

Result:

```
Key: id         Value: 1234      
Key: alert      Value: a-b       
Key: up         Value: 12.3      
Key: down       Value: 12.3
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic solution based on regular expressions might look like this:

```
String input = "id:1234 alert:a-b up:12.3 down:12.3";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\S+):(\\S+)").matcher(input);

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " = " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

This assumes you are looking for one or more non-whitespace characters, then a colon, then one or more non-whitespace characters.

Output:

```
id = 1234
alert = a-b
up = 12.3
down = 12.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `.split()` from the **String** class.

Check this out:

```
String line = "id:1234 alert:a-b up:12.3 down:12.3";
String []splittedLine = line.split(" ");
for(int i = 0; i <= splittedLine.length;i++){
   System.out.println(splittedLine[i]);
}
```

What you are doing here is splitting your string line on every whitespace character it found.
This is the result:

> id:1234 
>   alert:a-b 
>   up:12.3 
>   down:12.3